# Setting up an enclosure for multiple hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, connection, ethernet

I'm wondering of what I'd need/could do if I were to say, have several 1TB drives, and enclose them in a single tower/whatever and allow a single port (e.g. ethernet) access to them (so, instead of having them in one tower, I'd be able to access them all via ethernet instead via a single case).  Could I do this whilst avoiding the need to purchase another motherboard, CPU, etc and confine it to a PSU/CASE/something else to output access to the drives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could.  It is called a NAS enclosure.  For example the [D-Link DNS-323](http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=509) holds two hard disks.  These sorts of devices generally sell for less than $200.00.  Hard disks, of course, usually aren't included.  I have a similar device from D-Link and it works great.

Comment: +1  Many simple NAS devices like this as noted. D-Link one works well. Vendors like Western Digital and Buffalo sell complete solutions as well